# Defining a Fourier transform through a limiting process

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform

This is my first question here so pardon me if there are any mistakes.

In DSP course in Engineering, our professor stated the following

> Even when neither condition for existence of the CTFT is satisfied, we may still be able to define a Fourier transform through a limiting process.
>
> Let $x_n(t), n = 0,1,2,...$ denote a sequence of functions each of which has a valid CTFT $X_n(f)$.
>
> Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n(t) = x(t),$ a function that does not have a valid transform.
>
> If $X(f) = \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(f)$ exists, we call it the *generalized* Fourier transform of $x(t)$

I'm very skeptical about this definition, all my research so far didn't land any reference that states this definition (extension) directly, except for Dirac delta (not) function, which makes sense since Dirac delta itself is defined through a limit (not necessarily) and the structure of both Dirac delta and Fourier transform is preserved under this definition.

Here are some of my questions about the definition

- Is it unique?

> Suppose that $x(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty} = \lim_{n\to\infty}y_n,$ where $x_n \ne y_n$, does it still follow that $X(f) = \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(f) = \lim_{n\to\infty} Y_n(f)$ for any $x_n, y_n$?

- Is it a valid extension?

> Suppose that $x(t)$ has a valid Fourier transform, does it follow that for any $x_n(t)$ such that $x(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n(t)$, $X(f) = \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(f)$?

- Are the conditions stated above sufficient? That is for *any* function $x(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n(t)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(f)$ exists, $X(f)$ would be a valid transform?
- I would be glad if you could name further resources (or a proof of the definition) to help me understand it.

Comment: No it is most definitely not unique. You can often approach functions along infinitely many different paths. It is easy to come up with infinite many sequences of approximators to dirac delta for example.

Comment: @mathreadler Would any of these "infinite many sequences" have a different transformation, using the limiting process?

Comment: We can imagine the basis functions for the transformation changing in small steps just as we can imagine one function changing in small steps as a sequence of functions.